# Why does \chapter + \include make a blank page?

Tags: chapters

I'm writing a book with several chapters, and I've split every chapter to separate files. In my preamble, I have this:

```
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
...
```

File `chap1.tex`:

```
\chapter{Chapter text - Number 1}
Text text text
```

and similar for `chap2.tex` (and all other chapter files). This works as expected.

However, I recently thought that instead of having `\chapter{}` in the chapter files, I will move these to the preamble and just keep the substance in the chapter files. Like this:

```
\chapter{Chapter text - Number 1}
\include{chap1}

\chapter{Number 2}
\include{chap2}
```

and so on. However, the result of this was not as expected. I get a chapter heading (expected), but the rest of the page is completely blank. I have to turn page to get to the chapter contents.

Expected results was exactly the same as if I had `\chapter{}` inside the chapter files.

Why does the blank page happen if I split `\chapter{}` and the chapter contents?

Comment: Replace `\include{}` by `\input{}.`

Comment: From `texdef -t latex \include` we see that it calls `\@include`, which starts with `\clearpage`. This explains the result you observed.

Comment: @Sigur: worked. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/121799

Comment: The main difference between \include and \input is being able to implement \includeonly, so forcing a new page at the start and end makes sense.  I would put \chapter inside the included file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `texdef -t latex \include` we find:

> ```
> \include:
> macro:#1->\relax \ifnum \@auxout =\@partaux \@latex@error {\string \include \space cannot be nested}\@eha \else \@include #1 \fi
> ```

where we also can find `\@include`. So, from `texdef -t latex \@include` we find:

> ```
> \@include:
> macro:#1 ->\clearpage \if@filesw \immediate \write \@mainaux {\string \@input {#1.aux}}\fi \@tempswatrue \if@partsw \@tempswafalse
> \edef \reserved@b {#1}\@for \reserved@a :=\@partlist \do {\ifx
> \reserved@a \reserved@b \@tempswatrue \fi }\fi \if@tempswa \let
> \@auxout \@partaux \if@filesw \immediate \openout \@partaux #1.aux
> \immediate \write \@partaux {\relax }\fi \@input@ {#1.tex}\clearpage
> \@writeckpt {#1}\if@filesw \immediate \closeout \@partaux \fi \else
> \deadcycles \z@ \@nameuse {cp@#1}\fi \let \@auxout \@mainaux
> ```

and the very beginning shows `macro:#1 ->\clearpage`, that is, the first command is `\clearpage`.

This is why the `\include{file.tex}` clears the page before inserting the contents of `file.tex`.

For completeness, lets see: `texdef -t latex \clearpage`

> ```
> \clearpage:
> macro:->\ifvmode \ifnum \@dbltopnum =\m@ne \ifdim \pagetotal <\topskip \hbox {}\fi \fi \fi \newpage \write \m@ne {}\vbox {}\penalty -\@Mi
> ```

where we find `\newpage`.

As exercise to the reader, check `texdef -t latex \newpage`. Also, compare the above with `texdef -t latex \input`.